NelmioApiDocBundle logout path is not listed in API doc
I am setting up NelmioApiDocBundle v4 on my project.
The project is basically Rest API and all routes start with prefix /api.
The authentication is via Bearer token.
And there is also a route to revoke the token to which there is no controller method.
It is only defined in config/security.yaml:
    firewalls:
        api:
            pattern: ^/api(?!/doc$)
            lazy: true
            provider: jwt
            stateless: true
            jwt: ~
            logout:
                path: /api/revoke # <- route that I want to show up on API doc

packages/nelmio_api_doc.yaml:
nelmio_api_doc:
    # ...
    areas: # to filter documented areas
        path_patterns:
            - ^/api(?!/doc$) # Accepts routes under /api except /api/doc

With the current configuration all /api routes that have matching Controller are listed in API doc except /api/revoke.
When I run bin/console debug:router it lists api/revoke route:

And the route is working properly when I send request.
I don't understand why this bundle does not list that endpoint.

Found a solution in another question.
I don't know if there is a better solution but solution I found is to define that route manually in the configuration.
# /config/nelmio_api_doc.yaml
nelmio_api_doc:
    documentation:
        # ... 
        paths:
            /api/revoke:
                get:
                    summary: Revoke JWT Token
                    responses:
                        '200':
                            description: HTTP 200 upon successful token revocation

